# Make a menu item in Form1 checked true/false from other Forms

Tags: c#

How could I make a menu item checked as true/false in Form1 from other forms?

I just could change the text, enable/disable it from other forms but not changing the check state.

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast the item to a ToolStripMenuItem, as the Find method returns items of type ToolStripItem (which ToolStripMenuItem inherits from).

Example:

```
private void FindItAndCheck()
{
    ToolStripMenuItem item = 
       this.MainMenuStrip.Items.Find("exit", true).FirstOrDefault() 
       as ToolStripMenuItem;

    if (item == null) throw new ApplicationException("...");
    else
    {
        item.Checked = true;
    }
}
```